# How to include header file in .c from other directories

Tags: c, compilation, c-preprocessor

I'm working in this directory structure

```
root: Code
|--src
    |--client
        |--client.c
    |--server
        |--server.c
    |--lib
        |--utility.c
|--include
    |--prototype.h
    |--utility_lib.h
```

in `client.c` file, I have to include the `utility_lib.h` file.

With `#include "-I../../include/utility_lib.h"`
it doesn't work, probably the route is not correct.

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more usual way would be to change your build procedure (e.g. edit the `CFLAGS` in your `Makefile`) so to pass

```
-I $TOPDIR/include/
```

to your compiler. Inside a `Makefile` you'll probably define some make variable `TOPDIR=` and use it as `$(TOPDIR)`

Answer (score 6):

You can directly include the header file in your code:

```
// file client.c
#include "../../include/utility_lib.h"
```

Or you can tell your compiler where to find the header file:

```
// file client.c
#include <utility_lib.h>
```

Compilation command if the current directory is `client`:

```
gcc -c client.c -o client.o -I../../include
```

Compilation command if the current directory is `src`:

```
gcc -c src/client.c -o client.o -I../include
```

Answer (score 5):

It's just

```
#include "../../include/utility_lib.h"
```

`-I` flag you should add only to the compiler settings